# How to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss with the Django's date template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Edit : is there a way to easily convert `{{ value|date:"Z" }}` to one of the +hh:mm or -hh:mm formats (because date:"Z" returns xxxx or -xxxx seconds).

Show [this](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#valid-global-date-and-time-string) for more explanations about the needed format.

Thank you and sorry for my ugly english. ;)

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking. Perhaps you could rephrase it or explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clarifying here, it's the timezone offset that needs the colon, ie `2009-11-29T14:33:59-0600` in the above example should be `2009-11-29T14:33:59-06:00` to conform to the W3C guidelines.

Looking at the code at `django/utils/dateformat.py`:

```
  def O(self):
    "Difference to Greenwich time in hours; e.g. '+0200'"
    seconds = self.Z()
    return u"%+03d%02d" % (seconds // 3600, (seconds // 60) % 60)
```

You could edit *your local copy of django* to add the ':' so; `return u"%+03d:%02d" % (seconds // 3600, (seconds // 60) % 60)` or create your own template tag to do effectively the same thing. But probably the easiest is to compose the string in your view, and pass that along as a variable to the template.

It doesn't look like the HTML5 version of timezone is available out of the box.

[update]

On reflection you could probably do this;

```
>>> from django.utils import dateformat
>>> fmt = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 1, 12, 39, 48, 655867)
>>> str = dateformat.format(now, fmt)
>>> print str
2009-12-01T12:39:48+0000
>>>
```

and then add the ':'

```
>>> s = str[:-2] + ':' + str[-2:]
>>> s
u'2009-12-01T12:39:48+00:00'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Z you need O  (that's an "oh", not a "zero").

```
>>> from django.template import *
>>> Template('{% now "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" %}').render(Context())
u'2009-11-29T14:33:59-0600'
```

Comment: This is a better idea, however the HTML5 spec requires one of the +xx:xx or -xx:xx formats, and {% now "O" %} returns +xxxx or -xxxx.